# Library for rendering BPMN 2.0 in a browser

Tags: browser, bpmn

For a science project I'd need to render/display a BPMN 2.0 model in a web browser. 
Are there any libraries available to only render the diagram? (I don't need to edit it or do anything other than displaying it).
Bonus points if said library is also able to render/display petri nets.

The solution should be open source.

Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

**Activiti**

http://activiti.org/

- pretty advanced
- Java
- developed by several vendors, 
  e.g. http://signavio.com (free for university use: http://academic.signavio.com/ ) - the mentioned Red Hat jBPM  product seems to build upon activiti as well.

**Oryx**

http://code.google.com/p/oryx-editor/

- discontinued, Activiti is the successor

**Rigrr**

http://rapilabs.com/software/rigrr

- Simple (html, js)
- alpha
- new (2012)

**WAPAMA**

http://www.wapama.net/

- development stale
- pre alpha

**JUNG**

http://jung.sourceforge.net/

- flexible
- java
- ugly Java Browser Plugin required

ps: You question in very vague. e.g. you should let us know what kind of Library are you looking for? What is your coding envoironment?

Answer (score 8):

There is a package called `bpmn-js` from `bpmn.io` that is open sourced.  It can be found here:

http://bpmn.io/blog/posts/2014-bpmn-js-viewer-is-here.html

Answer (score 4):

With little effort you can create your own renderer. The blog post http://www.pleus.net/blog/?p=2142 explains how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

The camunda BPMN rendering library: https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpmn.js
You can see a demo here: http://camunda.org/share/

Answer (score 1):

The jBPM web-based editor (which currently has a dependency on guvnor, but that's being worked on) picks up where oryx left off. It's getting fairly mature, and the devs are quite responsive to bug reports/feature requests. You can output in PNG, PDF, and SVG formats.

http://surdilovic.wordpress.com/2012/04/10/jbpm-designer-version-2-1-released/

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/dmitryfar/diagram-viewer
Created for Activiti using REST. But you can just return jsons from you server for processdefinitions and etc.
Based on RaphaëlJS.

Comment: the project do not have a single line of documentation. Thats no good.

Answer (score 1):

**camunda-bpmn.js** project is not active, you can try bpmn-io/bpmn-js and see a demo: http://demo.bpmn.io/

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of.. it would be great to find one. If you take a look at the jBPM5 project you will find that there is an eclipse plugin to render BPMN2 models, we can extract the logic and create a rendering layer for web applications. When you mention "display in a browser" usually means a lot of things. Are you thinking in just a simple PNG? because the eclipse plugin already provide that export functionality.
Cheers

Comment: The end result should be something like a HTML5 canvas which can be modified with some AJAX queries. In Java I am currently experimenting with JUNG 2.0.1. As I need to define my own layouter, I might be able to port it over to javascript, if I find the time to learn it and HTML5 canvas :-)

Answer (score 0):

Exporting BPMN diagrams to SVG & XHTML was available in web based [Oryx editor](http://code.google.com/p/oryx-editor/). But that project is discontinued. If you can build the source code and get Oryx Editor to work, you can manipulate the generated SVG via javascript.