# Draw & Edit BPMN diagram in web-browser using javascript

Tags: bpmn

I am looking for an open source javascript framework for drawing and editing bpmn diagrams in browser. Can anyone provide any pointer regarding this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Library for rendering BPMN 2.0 in a browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8295110/library-for-rendering-bpmn-2-0-in-a-browser)

Answer (score 1):

I would have a look at http://bpmn.io/

There is an online demo, too.

Comment: ACK, but you should be aware for the modified MIT license, which adds the following clause: "The source code responsible for displaying the bpmn.io logo (two green cogwheels in a box) that links back to http://bpmn.io as part of rendered diagrams MUST NOT be removed or changed."

Comment: Except this clause, this answer the question. I would add that I don't blame the editor, for this is an interesting piece of software. And otherwise, many other editors would use it without even crediting clearly Camunda.